# Date column order by

Tags: sql-server

I have a date column `CreateDate (datetime, not null)` in my table.

Using the following where clause:

```
Where
    -- Code for 12 Months Back at a Time
    CreateDate >=  dateadd(month,datediff(month, 0, getdate())-12,0)
```

If I run my report say on March 1, 2017, I should get 12 months of data. I do.

I would like to order by `CreateDate` and get the following order

```
Mar 2017
Feb 2017
Jan 2017
Dec 2016
Nov 2016
Oct 2016
Sep 2016
Aug 2016
Jul 2016
Jun 2016
May 2016
Apr 2016
```

Here is the complete query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  tblCourtAttorneysAssigned.CourtAssignment AS [CourtAssignment], 
  tblCourtAttorneysAssigned.AttorneyBarNumber AS [AttorneyBarNumber], 
  tblCourtAttorneysAssigned.AttorneyFirstName AS [AttorneyFirstName], 
  tblCourtAttorneysAssigned.AttorneyLastName AS [AttorneyLastName],
  --tblCourtAttorneysAssigned.CaseNo, 
  --tblPeople.LastName, 
  --tblPeople.FirstName, 
  tblCourtAttorneysAssigned.HowAssigned AS [HowAssigned], 
  CONVERT( VARCHAR(10), tblCourtAttorneysAssigned.CreateDate, 101) AS[CreateDate] 



FROM   tblBookIn
  INNER JOIN tblOffense ON tblBookIn.BookInID = tblOffense.BookInID
  INNER JOIN tblPeople ON tblBookIn.PersonID = tblPeople.PersonID
  INNER JOIN tblCourtAttorneysAssigned ON tblOffense.CaseNo =  tblCourtAttorneysAssigned.CaseNo
WHERE  CourtAssignment LIKE 'M%'
  AND 
  -- Code for 12 Months Back at a Time
   CreateDate >=  dateadd(month,datediff(month, 0, getdate())-12,0)



ORDER by
[CreateDate] asc
--courtassignment ASC, 
 -- AttorneyLastName ASC;
```

Thanks

Comment: If `CreateDate` is a `DateTime` field as you've stated in your post, why can you not do `CreateDate desc`?

Comment: Can you write down the complete query?

Comment: "But, CreateDate desc doesn't work." In what way does it not work?

Comment: Sorry, hatchet. Well, yes it does sort, but NOT in the order like I outlined.

Comment: Let me add...when I copy my results to Excel and sort on createdate column with the Order being "Newest to Oldest" the sort order "works".

Comment: I added my complete code to my post.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you are using `order by CreateDate desc` but you have aliased CreateDate in your query to be something like `format(CreateDate, 'MMM yyyy') as CreateDate`

So your `order by` will need to know you want it to use the original value instead of the new value that is being returned with the same name.

Try `order by mytablename.CreateDate desc`

---

Update after question edited to include query:

change your `order by` to:

```
order by tblCourtAttorneysAssigned.CreateDate desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use order by clause at the end

```
SELECT     { fn MONTHNAME(OrderDate) } AS MonthName, YEAR(OrderDate) AS Year, SUM(TotalValue) AS Profits
FROM         [Order]
WHERE     (YEAR(OrderDate) = @year)
GROUP BY { fn MONTHNAME(OrderDate) }, YEAR(OrderDate) 
ORDER BY { fn MONTH(OrderDate) }, YEAR(OrderDate)
```

or

you can do like this

```
SELECT     CASE { fn MONTH(OrderDate) } 
            when 0 then 'JAN'
            when 1 then 'FEB'
            when 2 then 'MAR'
            when 3 then 'APR'
            when 4 then 'MAY'
            when 5 then 'JUN'
            when 6 then 'JUL'
            when 7 then 'AUG'
            when 8 then 'SEP'
            when 9 then 'OCT'
            when 10 then 'NOV'
            when 11 then 'DEC'
           END
      AS MonthName, YEAR(OrderDate) AS Year, SUM(TotalValue) AS Profits
    FROM         [Order]
    WHERE     (YEAR(OrderDate) = @year)
    GROUP BY { fn MONTH(OrderDate) }, YEAR(OrderDate) 
    ORDER BY { fn MONTH(OrderDate) }, YEAR(OrderDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, I have resolved the issue by removing the Convert on the date field and fixing the format in SSRS.

Thanks,